# Use integration by parts to prove an equality

Tags: integration

Let $f_p(x,t) = (1-x\sin^2(t))^{p-\frac{1}{2}}$ with $p \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in ]-\infty,1[$ and $t \in [0,\pi/2]$.

Consider now.

$$F_p(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2} f_p(x,t) dt$$

I have to prove the following equality.

$$(2p+1)F_{p+1}(x)-2p(2-x)F_p(x)+(2p-1)(1-x)F_{p-1}(x) = 0$$

I have an indication which is to integrate by parts the following expression.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2t) f_p(x,t) dt$$

The integration by parts give me something like that, but I still can't conclude to the equality.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2t) f_p(x,t) dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} (2p-1)x\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)f_{p-1}(x,t) dt$$

Comment: Does expanding $(2p+1)F_{p+1}(x)-2p(2-x)F_p(x)+(2p-1)(1-x)F_{p-1}(x)$ not help?

Comment: Don't think so. I tried to make appear $f_{p+1}$ somewhere in the integration by parts equality, remove all $\sin$ or $\cos$ and then subtract the two terms of the equality to have something null and find the equality. Perhaps a bad way ...

Comment: Maybe try differentiating under the integral sign?

Comment: Just for your curioisity (but totally out of scope) : $F_p(x)$ shows a "closed form" expression in terms of hypergeometric functions. And the equality holds.

Comment: @Reveillark I just tried, seems to be a good idea but, still not possible to get asked equality ...

Comment: @Shuri2060 Yes, $\left[\sin(2t)f_p(x,t)\right]^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 = 0$ and $\frac{1}{2}(p-\frac{1}{2}) \sin^2(2t) = (2p-1) \left( \frac{\sin(2t)}{2} \right)^2 = (2p-1) \sin^2(t) \cos^2(t)$.

Comment: @MB78 My apologies - didn't see it/missed an $x$

Comment: Perhaps this form might be slightly more helpful? $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2t) f_p(x,t) dt=\frac{x}{2}\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\sin^2(2t)f_{p-1}(x,t)\,\,\,dt$$

$$=\frac{x}{2}\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0(1-\cos^2(2t))f_{p-1}(x,t)\,\,\,dt$$

$$=\frac{x}{2}\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(F_{p-1}(x) - \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\cos^2(2t)f_{p-1}(x,t)\,\,\,dt\right)$$ Integrating the last term by parts again might help

Comment: On second thoughts maybe not integrating it again - it doesn't come out nicely

Comment: @Shuri2060 Tried with the form you proposed, but still can't conclude.

Comment: I haven't got much either rn - letting $$J_p=(2p+1)\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2t) f_p(x,t) dt$$ I only have $$J_p-J_{p-1}=(2p-1)(F_{p-1}-F_p)$$Out of interest, would you mind sharing where you got this question from?

Comment: @Shuri2060 It's just a summer exercice question ... How do you find your expression for $J_p-J_{p-1}$ ?

Comment: $f_p=(1-x\sin^2t)f_{p-1}$, so $$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\cos(2t)f_p\,\,\,dt=(2p-1)\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0(\cos^2t)(f_{p-1}-f_p)\,\,\,dt$$ and you should find it after some rearrangement using $\cos^2t=\frac{\cos(2t)+1}{2}$ on the next step (hope I didn't make an algebraic error)

Comment: @Shuri2060 Yes, it's working. Now I will look if it can help.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Inspiring your idea, but writing $\cos^2(t) = 1-\sin^2(t)$ instead of $\frac{\cos(2t)+1}{2}$, I found something like this.

$$xG_p(x) = (2p-1)((x-1)F_{p-1}(x)+(2-x)F_p(x)-F_{p+1}(x))$$

With $G_p(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2t) f_p(x,t) dt$.

Comment: That looks a lot more hopeful. I'd say you're nearly there?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have to rearrange $xG_p(x)$ with some $F_p$ functions.

Comment: @Shuri2060 It's working fine, thanks for the help.